# ZeroMQ support in Bitcoin Core 0.16.0 out-of-the-box?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, zeromq, lightning-network-daemon

In my [previous question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74687/lightning-node-daemon-hangs-at-waiting-for-chain-backend-to-finish-sync-start), I'm wondering why Lightning Networks `lnd` cannot talk to my Bitcoin Core `bitcoind` backend.

The docs for `lnd` says it [requires ZeroMQ compiled into `bitcoind`](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#running-lnd-using-the-bitcoind-or-litecoind-backend).  Does the binary version of [Bitcoin Core `bitcoind` 0.16.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) contain ZeroMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the official Bitcoin Core v0.16.0 binary works perfectly well with LND, no self compiling necessary.

Comment: any idea what the problem might be on my [prior question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74687/lightning-node-daemon-hangs-at-waiting-for-chain-backend-to-finish-sync-start)?  Have you seen lnd 0.4.1-beta working with bitcoind 0.16.0?

Comment: I cannot really answer that, two suggestions: 1) ask in the LND slack (see invitation link at  the bottom of the [Lightning Labs engineering](https://lightning.engineering/) page), or 2) check my [Raspberry Pi guide](https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/README.md) for key differences, it works with the same basic setup.